# Why does this time signature have addition?

Tags: time-signatures

I found this piece of music that has an odd time signature. I unfortunately do not have the music with me, but the time signature looks like this:

```
2+2+3+2
   8
```

I have been playing this as 9/8, but am still confused as what this means. Can somebody please help me? If I can get a picture of the sheet music, I will upload it.

Comment: Could it be [Sting's "I Hung My Head"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnwmOfmZbb0)?  That's a well-known pop example of this particular *composite meter*.

Comment: It was not, but I will go take a look at that song. If I remember correctly it was Balkan music

Comment: My next guess was going to be Romanian or Moldovan folk music.

Comment: You should play it exactly as instructed, as 2+2+3+2, with the accents on the 1 of each number. Playing it in 9/8, i.e. in triplets, is a clear violation of the composer's intent.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is 9/8, **BUT** the 'normal' 9/8 is three sets of three quavers - thus the bottom number of 8.

2+2+3+2 also equals 9, and it's written that way so the player can understand what the composer wants as far as emphases are concerned, not the usual **1**23**2**23**3**23, (or **1**23**4**56**7**89), but instead, **1**2**3**4**5**67**8**9.

Just a different way to put emphases on certain beats within the bar, and a better way to show than changing the time signature every couple of bars!

Answer (score 10):

It means 9/8, but the eighths are grouped 2, 2, 3 and 2 (instead of the standard 3+3+3). It could theoretically have been written as alternate bars of 2/4 and 5/8.
Often this kind of additive time signature is superfluous: the beaming usually shows the rhythmic subdivision.

Comment: That might be interpreted as the 5/8 12-345 instead of the expected 123-45.

Comment: @Tim I don't think I've ever seen 5/8 where the subdivision mattered and wasn't clear from the beaming

Comment: @PiedPiper I've played some new work where it constantly but unpredictably switched the subdivision of 7 back and forth (4 + 3, 3 + 4, 2 + 3 + 2), and tried to indicate it with symbols like triangles and squares. (Or maybe I'm just remembering drawing them into my part to keep track of Copland's *El Salón México*...)

Answer (score 1):

It means that each bar (measure) has 9 quavers (eighth-notes) divided into four beats of 2,2,3,2 quavers. Sounds fun.